# Android - record sound and check sound volume

Tags: android

I am trying to find out if my device is recording audio correctly (Volume of recorded audio is not too low and actually the recorded file has sound). The way I tried doing it is:

> start recording --> play sound --> stop recording --> get file recorded max volume

The code I used to record sound:

```
public void playSound() {
        File myDataPath = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator + ".CheckAudio");
        if (!myDataPath.exists())
            myDataPath.mkdirs();
        recordFile = myDataPath + File.separator + "Recording_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + ".mp3";
        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING), 0);
        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION), 0);
        Uri defaultRingtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        try {
            md = new MediaRecorder();
            md.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            md.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            md.setOutputFile(recordFile);
            md.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            md.prepare();
            md.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
            recording = false;
            removeItem("Unable to record audio, please try again."); // (Show toast)
            return;
        }
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getActivity(), defaultRingtoneUri);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    md.stop();
                    md.release();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = null;
                   // get recordfile volume
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            removeItem("Unable to play audio");
            sound = false;
        }
    }
```

However, I can't find out how to analyze the mp3 file created and check if it is not empty (from sound), is there a library or another way?

I hope you guys understood what I am trying to achieve as my English is pretty bad, Thanks.

**EDIT:(Some more explaination)** 
If you play sound (ringtone or something) while recording sound from microphone, the decibels recorded should be around 90 decibels. meaning the sound playing working and also the microphone, but if the decibels recorded around 30 means only microphone is working, and playing sound not, if the decibels are around zero then the microphone is not working.

Comment: First of all can you find the file that was created? Can you open it with a different application than yours and see if the sound is indeed recorded?

Comment: @GeorgeD I want to do it in the same application, however, doing this in background while other things occur is an option. I added some more information about what I am willing to find ( at the bottom of the answer). thanks.

Comment: I know that you want to do that from the same application but lets just leave that for a moment, try opening the file from another application that exists on your device and see if it has in fact recorded anything. Lets verify whether the recording functionality is being implemented correctly.

Comment: @GeorgeD oh, yes, I tried to actually play the file using media player and is was working fine. Using a decibels reader on same device I got to around 85

Comment: have you tried googling for "java spectrum analyzer library"? If not, I suggest you do. If you did and something is not working, please update the question. If you just want to make someone else do your work for you, I'm guessing 100 rep points is not enough to buy something to eat, or some candy at least. And in the last case, thanks, people like you are transforming this site into a free outsourcing agency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a visualiser to visualise real time if  recording sound is getting too low or too loud.

I have build a project which visualise recording sound strength via  bar graph . Higher  the bar louder the recorded sound lower the bar low decibels .

This project also have inapp player which allow user to play all his recordings. The inbuilt player also visualise playback sound data.

I am suggesting this because I thought this is what you are trying to achieve  in
start recording --> play sound --> stop recording --> get file recorded max volume.

Instead of getting max volume each time  you can rely on visualiser to keep an eye on recorder if recording file is getting recorded above acceptable decibals.

You can find source code on github

https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-Audio-Recorder-Visualization-Master